# JXTable background image don't renders

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

I am trying to generate a JXTable with a background image ( a text would be fine as well). Here is my extended JXTable class:

```
public class JXTableWithBackground extends JXTable{

    ImageIcon image;
    public JXTableWithBackground(ParticipantTableModel pTableModel, ImageIcon image){
        super(pTableModel);
        this.image=image;
    }
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column){
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer( renderer, row, column);
        // We want renderer component to be transparent so background image is visible
        if( c instanceof JComponent )((JComponent)c).setOpaque(false);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //draw image in centre
        final int imageWidth = image.getIconWidth();
        final int imageHeight = image.getIconHeight();
        final Dimension d = getSize();
        final int x = (d.width - imageWidth)/2;
        final int y = (d.height - imageHeight)/2;
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), x, y, null, null);
        super.paint(g);
    }
```

The image don't shows up - I only see white space. Any idea?

Comment: The cell component might still render non-opaque pixels due to its background color. Did you try returning non-opaque empty labels as a test?

Comment: @Thomas I just tried it and it's still white

Comment: Please also note that the table itself might have a background thus calling `super.paint(g)` might actually completely hide your image.

Comment: @Thomas right, setting the opaque value to false made the image visible!

Comment: Great. I'll add an answer. :)

Comment: SwingX or plain vanilla Swing: for custom painting the method to override is paintComponent (_not_ paint). For visual decorations in SwingX, see @Robin's answer. Interesting (and a slight beware), though: opaqueness is not one of visual properties guaranteed to be reset on each config round, so you can't re-use the same ComponentProvider across opaque and not-opaque tables (or lists or trees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

The problem seems to be that the table itself is not rendered transparently. Setting the table itself to opaque = false helps.

Answer (score 1):

For `SwingX` the recommended way to for example use an opaque component for rendering is to use the [`Highlighter`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx/1.6.1/swingx-1.6.1-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/decorator/Highlighter.html) interface. So instead of overriding the `prepareRenderer` method, it is recommended to write your `Highlighter` and use the [`JXTable#setHighlighters`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx/1.6.1/swingx-1.6.1-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html#setHighlighters%28org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.Highlighter...%29) method to set in on the table